# PHP cannot get property of undefined DOM parser

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ to scrape some data, here's the DOM
[image: DOM]

My PHP

```
$dom = $html->find('.pdng10',0)->find('.couponInfo');

foreach ($dom as $data) {
        $off = $data->find('.width60 .coupon-box .height1 span',0)->plaintext;
}
```

But why I got  cannot get property of undefined? I see no wrong in my code above.

Comment: omg hello what happen here?

Comment: because there's no .pdng10 there :)